# Image upload to firebase storage with React Jodit WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage, jodit

I'm using Jodit to create a WYSIWYG editor. My application is developed on React JS and Firebase handles the database and storage.

I am unable to add a custom function to allow image upload to firebase using Jodit Editor. Is there any possibility to add this directly? I would like to avoid using a function using NodeJs for image uploads only.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workarounds:

1. Enable the following option within the default image uploader then use a cloud function to convert the base64 string to firebase storage and replace the string with the publicly accessible URL.

   "uploader": { "insertImageAsBase64URI": true },
2. Create a http-accessible endpoint with cloud functions to process the image according to [this documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/v.2/doc/tutorial-filebrowser-options.html).